# How to define PyCharm to have anaconda as an interpreter?

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

I tried searching for the python path, but that did not work.

How can I use the anaconda python interpreter in PyCharm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Anaconda gives a detailed explanation on how to do that](https://web.archive.org/web/20151231205505/https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration).

The path that you want to add is `~/anaconda/bin/python` (only in case it isn't automatically provided by PyCharm).

Comment: I try doing that, but it's stuck on loading, and does not set the python path.

Comment: @Ian could it be that it is `~anaconda3/bin/python`? For some reason this does not work for me.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

The path that worked for me is `~/anaconda3/bin/python3.7`